# Best approach for background repeated image using foundation 4 framework?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm using the foundation4 framework. I want a repeating tiled background. So I've created a custom css file and dropped in the following CSS.

```
 body {
 background: url(img/floorboardsbg.jpg) repeat; 
 }
```

This works, but I wanted to make sure there is not a better approach or that this will have any negative impact when trying to create a responsive site design?

Comment: It should not be a problem. I'd suggest using a smaller image which gets tiled many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that shouldn't give you any problems, usually for repeated images they should be as small as the patter is for better performance. 
being responsive or not the repeat will fill however big the container is.